# Live backup lxc container

Tags: lxc, linux-containers

I know multiple ways to backing up a lxc container, but all of them, as far as I see, involve stop the container first. I would like to know if there is a way to make a live backup of the containers of course without stopping it.

Comment: You can snapshot the running container, then do what you like with the snapshot, ie image then export.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone With the snapshot utility of lxc, I tried and it does not work, but making a **tar.gz** backup did work and I don't be force to stop the container. So I think I find my solution thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done in an officially supported way. LXD does have this functionality though.